# How do I search a corpus for words with a specific suffix?

Tags: discussion

I am trying to search BCCWJ for words which contain the suffix ～面 (づら). An example of the type of word I am looking for is 先輩面 (せんぱいづら).

I tried using *面 but it doesn't seem to be correct. And if I just search for 面, obviously all the other words containing it will also appear. So is there a way to enter a search term which will just include the suffix entries?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, unfortunately there is not a way to search for just suffix entries on the free-access online version of BCCWJ (少納言、'shonagon'), as it only has character string search capability.

I haven't used the registered-access online version (中納言、'chuunagon'), but I understand that it includes some morphological coding, which should help with your query. For instance, I know that you can search by part of speech (品詞) and that there are various options surrounding suffixes (接尾辞) within that. But, as I say, I've not used this version of the database myself, so I can't say for sure that it would be possible to do the kind of search you are hoping to do even in the upgraded database.

Hope that helps -- good luck!